# Common MouseMove Event for ComboBoxItem WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I add one `MouseMove` **Event** for all the ComboBoxItems in a ComboBox?

Below is what I tried.

```
<ComboBox Name="Test>  
    <ComboBoxItem MouseMove=TestMenuItem_MouseMove">Item1</ComboBoxItem>  
    <ComboBoxItem MouseMove=TestMenuItem_MouseMove">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Is there any easy or standard way to write a common code for above instead of writing event for each and every ComboBoxItem?

I would like to do this from XAML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<ComboBox Name="Test">  
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="TestMenuItem_MouseMove"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>  
    <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```